# Get subset x elements before and x elements after LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list and i need a subset of it which has the 5 previous elements to the one currently in the for loop and 5 elements after, so in total a list of 10 elements. Ignoring the current item in the loop.

I am currently achieving this as follows:

```
var currentIndex = myList.ClassName.FindIndex(a => a.Id == plate.Id);
var fromIndex = currentIndex - 5;
if (fromIndex < 0) fromIndex = 0;
var toIndex = currentIndex + 5;
if ((myList.ClassName.ElementAtOrDefault(toIndex) == null))
    toIndex = myList.ClassName.Count - 1;


var subsetList = myList.ClassName.GetRange(fromIndex, (11));
comparisonPlates.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
```

However i am sure there is a much better and more efficient way of doing this using LINQ, any guidance?

Comment: If your logic depends on indexes so heavily you should not use LINQ. That is neither readable nor efficient.

Comment: I just need the most efficient way to get a subset of elements before and after.

Comment: If your current approach works, use that. `List.GetRange` is exactly what you need.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) so you have all your elements surrounding your current index (and the current index).

To remove the current index, either add a RemoveAt; or use several Skip/Take (Skip/Take to take the elements before yours, and Skip/Take to take the elements after)

With a sample :

```
const int currentIndex = 12;
const int nbElements = 5;
List<string> results = items.Skip(currentIndex - nbElements).Take(nbElements).Concat(items.Skip(currentIndex + 1).Take(nbElements)).ToList();
```

Comment: not sure how to use this correctly could you provide a workable example?

Comment: Beware that `Union` returns distinct values. `Concat` is more suitable in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I feel is a little more readable.

```
var numElements = 5;
var fromIndex = currentIndex <= numElements ? 0 : currentIndex - numElements - 1;
var toIndex = myList.Count() - currentIndex <= numElements ? myList.Count() : currentIndex + numElements;

var subsetList = myList.Skip(fromIndex).Take(toIndex - fromIndex);
```

### EDIT:

I'd suggest using Ripple's answer because of the performance reasons mentioned.  I wasn't aware of the implications of skip/take, but after looking it up, it does make sense.  For a small list of items, it won't matter, but it would with a sizable amount of data.

Comment: You still must remove the current element.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use LINQ to generate indices:

```
var subset = Enumerable.Range(currentIndex - 5, 5)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(currentIndex + 1, 5))
    .SkipWhile(index => index < 0)
    .TakeWhile(index => index < items.Count)
    .Select(index => items[index])
    ;
```

This can be more efficient than the way using `items.Skip` operation, because `items.Skip(n)` will internally do `IEnumerator.MoveNext` through n elements one by one, that is, the greater your `currentIndex`, the less efficient.

Of course `SkipWhile` or `TakeWhile` in the code above is slightly inefficient for the same reason, but it totally loops always only 10 times.
If you hate that inefficiency, you can calculate indices and counts (parameters of `Enumerable.Range`)  beforehand and eliminate those.
(In my opinion, my code above seems more readable.)

In addition, [Runtime Complexity](http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.jp/2010/03/runtime-complexity-of-net-generic.html) of the indexer(`[]`) of List is O(1), that means `items[index]` takes constant time regardless of `index` value or the size of your List.